# Name giving ceremony

Tags: names, brit-milah

At the Brit Milah parents give name to their son. Is there a seperate ceremony or is it part of the Brit Milah? And does this name-giving-part have a name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The Circumcision Ceremony in a Nutshell](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1472861/jewish/The-Circumcision-Ceremony-in-a-Nutshell.htm)

While it is a separate section of the ceremony. it is part of that ceremony and done at the same time. Since the child as a member of Bnai Yisrael is entering the "covenant", he is given his identity at that moment. It  is called *kriyas hashem* (calling or announcement of the name). Thus the person who will read the bracha that gives the name is announced

> Rabbi Ploni is honored with *kriyas hashem*

As @DoubleAA points out the person does not have to be a rabbi and the announcement can be made in any language. I just gave a typical example.

@msh210 points out that this is actually not a requirement of the bris even though most people do so and make it an "honor".

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that it is a part of the actual ceremony, albeit obviously not integral (מעכב).

1. The text of the naming ceremony contains many explicit and implicit references to ברית and מילה

   - ואעבור עליך ואראך מתבוססת **בדמיך** ואמר לך **בדמיך** חיי ואמר לך **בדמיך** חיי
   - 'זכר לעולם **בריתו** וגו
   - 'אשר **כרת** את אברהם וגו
   - ויעמידיה ליעקב לחק לישראל **ברית** עולם
   - '**וימל** אברהם את יצחק בנו וגו
   - 'כשם שנכנס **לברית** וכו
2. When the same person makes the naming as the ברכות, the wine is drunk after the naming, clearly rendering this an extension of the ברכותת, otherwise it would be a ברכה לבטלה.

Comment: "the wine is drunk after the naming" That is not true in all communities. Some drink before naming.

Comment: As you have stated, the naming is not obligatory. If that's the case, I guess one can say the remainder of the paragraph with all the different verses without the naming. I've never seen it done, but, maybe for my grandson (besha'ah tovah), I'll set a precedent.

Comment: @DoubleAA As I noted, that is because it is usually split between two people, and we want the person who made the blessing on the wine to drink something, but this is definitely not a requirement.

Comment: @DanF I meant to say that it does not obviously prevent the מילה from being effective. I would never suggest that one not name a boy at his ברית, save for some situation where he is not well for an extended period of time, where some communities may give the name prior to the actual מילה. Otherwise, I do not see any reason to depart from the established practice of ALL communities.

Comment: @joseph that's just not true. Some have the person drink first even if he's going to continue to say the naming part.

Comment: @DoubleAA I cannot say for sure, but since there are those who do not, I would say that it is safe to say that this shows that it is part of the מילה ceremony according to those who do. I do not believe the point of contention between the two practices is that those who drink in between think that it is not a part of the מילה ceremony. After all, I assume you agree with my first point.

Comment: I'm not sure what your "first point" is (but I don't agree it's part of the "ceremony", since I don't know what constitutes a Chalot "ceremony"). Incidentally some communities name the child before the cup of wine is even brought out.